# Read network-data send by Colasoft Packet Player with Qt

Tags: qt, udp, wireshark, packet-sniffers

I am trying to read the data send by Colasoft Packet Player via Qt.

I use a loopbackadapter with IP 192.168.1.99 and Wireshark shows me something like this:

SourceIP: 192.168.1.1

SourcePort: 40102

DestinationIP: 224.0.1.12

DestinationPort: 49156

But using those IPs and Ports, Qt QUdpSocket does not show any data.
When I try to read over all ports and IPs i receive data, so the programm should work, but it seems, I do not get any data send by Colasoft Packet Player.

What do I do wrong?

Thank you!

```
MyUDPSocket::MyUDPSocket(QObject *parent)
: QObject(parent)
{
    socket = new QUdpSocket(this);


    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 40102);
    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("127.0.0.1"), 49156);

    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("224.0.1.12"), 40102);
    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("224.0.1.12"), 49156);

    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.1.1"), 40102);
    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.1.1"), 49156);

    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.1.99"), 40102);
    //socket->bind(QHostAddress("192.168.1.99"), 49156);


    //socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 40102);
    //socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 49156);

    socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 49156, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);   
    socket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress("224.0.1.12"));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
}

void MyUDPSocket::readyRead()
{
        // when data comes in
        QByteArray buffer;
        buffer.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());

        QHostAddress sender;
        quint16 senderPort;

        // qint64 QUdpSocket::readDatagram(char * data, qint64 maxSize, 
        //                 QHostAddress * address = 0, quint16 * port = 0)
        // Receives a datagram no larger than maxSize bytes and stores it in data. 
        // The sender's host address and port is stored in *address and *port 
        // (unless the pointers are 0).

        socket->readDatagram(buffer.data(), buffer.size(),
                             &sender, &senderPort);
        qDebug() << "\n+-------------------------------";
        qDebug() << "|Message from:" << sender.toString(); 
        qDebug() << "|Message port:" << senderPort;
        qDebug() << "|Message:" << buffer;
        qDebug() << "+-------------------------------\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address `224.0.1.12` corresponds to multicast.
So, you want to join multicast stream, see [`bool QUdpSocket::joinMulticastGroup(const QHostAddress & groupAddress)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html#joinMulticastGroup), from that document:

> Note that if you are attempting to join an IPv4 group, your socket
>   must not be bound using IPv6 (or in dual mode, using
>   QHostAddress::Any). You must use QHostAddress::AnyIPv4 instead.

There is also Qt [Multicast Receiver Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-multicastreceiver-example.html).

---

**Update due to original question code changes**

I verified that the original code before edit (without `joinMulticastGroup()`) was able to receive normal unicast UDP packets to port 49156. So, the code worked as a server listening bound port.

Now with `joinMulticastGroup()` and replacement `QHostAddress::Any` -> `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` the code is able to receive multicast stream from VLC player.

So, the coding issues are resolved. Other possible issues:

- routing setup
- incorrectly formed packed by Colasoft Packet Player

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I edited my code like it is shown in the example and also tried to implement the example code but I still do not receive any data. `socket->bind(QHostAddress::Any, 49156, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress); socket->joinMulticastGroup(QHostAddress("224.0.1.12"));`

Comment: @honiahaka10 Are you sure that all functions are completed successfully? You can check the returned values. For example, `bind()` may fail on Windows with `QUdpSocket::ShareAddress` option when another process is already bound on the specified port: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719515/qudpsocket-bind-for-multicast-with-shareaddress-fails

Comment: I already checked the returned values of `bind()` and `joinMulticastGroup()`. Both returned `true`.

Comment: @honiahaka10 You can check your network setup. At first check that Colasoft Packet Player indeed sends proper multicast traffic that you can join by some other application, for example with VLC player.

Comment: How can I check this? (And how would VLC help me?)

Comment: @honiahaka10 If you see packets in Wireshark it means that such packer are created. However, it does not mean that those packets are routed to your expected destination. That question is not about coding. It is related to system administration and it is very specific to your setup, for example http://serverfault.com/questions/205648/how-do-i-add-a-multicast-route-in-windows-7 or http://serverfault.com/questions/262634/how-do-i-know-if-ip-multicasting-is-enabled-on-my-network-in-windows. VLC is a nice tool that can be used to generate video mcast and receive it on other client to test setup.

Comment: @honiahaka10 Note that you must use `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` instead of `QHostAddress::Any` to join an IPv4 group. With that fix I was able to verify that the code "as is" is able to receive my manually created by VLC stream at least on Linux.

Comment: Did I understand this correctly? I start any video-stream with vlc and check, whether my programm can receive the UDP-packages? And what do I have to do/check afterwards?

Comment: @honiahaka10 At first you can check that your code after the fix `QHostAddress::AnyIPv4` is able to receive your stream from Colasoft Packet Player. If it fails you can create a stream by VLC to check that your code works. Also you can use your Colasoft Packet Player as a streamer and VLC as a client to verify routing.

Comment: How should VLC receive the data from Colasoft Packet Player? It is not sending (normal) video data. My coworker had a look above my code and think it should work, since his code looks the same. He also thinks, that the problem might be the loopback adapter and that I am not using another computer as a server for Colasoft. I now streamed a file with VLC using `vlc -vvv small.mp
4 --sout udp:224.0.1.12:40102 --ttl 12` and my programm received the packages.

Comment: @honiahaka10 It did not realize that Colasoft Packet Player cannot stream video. Anyway, now your coding issues are resolved, since you are able to receive either unicast or multicast UDP. For routing issues you can try create another question (maybe here http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Okay I will try that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Btw: Colasoft Packet Player is just sending UDP-Requests which were earlier captured by a packet-sniffer.